# Development right on network drive

Tags: git, workflow

I'm a member of a small PHP development team inside a larger company. We have our own development and production server and since both of them are on a local network and the applications we are developing run strictly locally and are not intended to be public, we develop on the development server and have no local environments. Each of us has the source codes stored locally on disk, but we have IDEs set up to automatically synchronize all changes to DEV server immediately (basically after every save).

This has been very benefitial historically since every developer has his own projects and collaboration of more developers on one project almost never happened. But now our team is getting bigger and we are dealing with some changes along the way. The main thing being that we need to have some sort of versioning system. Git to be more exact.

Is there any way to implement some sort of a git workflow to this setup? I mean, installing Git is as easy as it gets, but we want to enjoy the benefits of e.g. integrating git to IDE and being able to see who did what, when, etc. Right now all we are able to do without changing our workflow completely is to install git on DEV server and commit directly there. But that would mean that each person would work on the code locally, the code would be synchronized to the server and he would need to connect there and commit there. That seems just wrong to me..

Can you see a way to implement git without having to set up local environment on our machines?

Comment: "we develop on the development server and have no localhost environments. Each of us has the source codes stored locally on disk". So, every developer has its own machine? If yes, then simply make each local copy a git repository.

Comment: Yes, we all have our owm machines. The problem is, that since we don't have localhost, the only way to see and test the code is on the DEV server. That's why all the local changes are automatically uploaded there. If we wanted to keep this working, it would collide with git repositories, because we would commit our changes to our local copies, but upload them to the server as well. This would most certainly raise conflicts in every push to the repository on DEV server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have each developer work on its local git repository, synchronised with a central repository.

When a developer thinks his changes are ready, he can simply push his commits.

- Either, the push is fast-foward, then everything is fine and the changes are automatically applied.
- Or, the push is non-fast-foward. This is the case when other developers have pushed in between and conflicts may occur. So, the developer has to pull the other changes and merge his commits, possibly resolving conflicts.

  Git neither introduced conflicts, nor does it circumvent conflicts (although some assume this). Git just helps you *noticing* and *managing* these conflicts.
  How have you, until now, managed conflicts? For instance, two developers changing a line in the same file?
  Avoiding conflicts is all about your team's organisation.

You can also set up a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) so that the central repository automatically updates the files of the web server whenever new commits have been pushed (although first running automated tests is clearly more advisably).

**Edit**

Your development strategy is, imho, neither suitable for even medium-sized teams nor medium-sized software projects.

- The large the team, the more people work concurrently on the code. What if two developers change the same file? If Dev1 saves his work, will the work of Dev2 be overwritten just because he has not saved his file? If Dev2 saves his file, will he overwrite Dev1's work?
- The larger the software project, the more likely you need to change multiple files in parallel (e.g. changing a function's signature). So if you change the first file, the complete software is broken now, and you automatically deployed this broken software to your server!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I completely agree, that tha way we do things now is not great. Till now, our IDE itself was checking the conflicts. Every programmer was alerted the second he opened a file that has a newer version on the server. So basically we managed the conflicts the same way as we would via git, but on a very basic level (if the file is newer on server, just download it, or merge it to your local version).

Comment: So if I understand your answer correctly, we should basically switch off the automatic upload to DEV and do it via commit/push in git. For that we need to have a working localhost because if we only had the application running on DEV, we would work in the dark and we would need to commit and push every change to DEV just to see it in action - which would very easily break the application. Am I right?

Comment: I would say, you should *replace* the automatic upload with (manual) commits/pushes. Basically, for every change, you may create a commit and push it, so have essentially have the basic workflow. However, as a developer, I would first always want to make sure my changes do not break anything before uploading it anywhere. So a local testing environment - if feasible - is always a good thing. But you do not require it. — Anyway, currently you are also working in the dark and may break things - just that the cycles are much shorter than it would probably be with git.

Comment: And, could you please change your question so you replace "localhost" with "local server", "local testing environment" or similar? `localhost` simply denotes the machine you are working on, as in `ping localhost`. You actually mean a web-server running on every machine as testing environment.

Comment: Thanks again for all the input. I was trying to figure out some other solution that would make more sense, but as I see it (considering all you said), this is the best alternative.